# Javascript substr(); limit by word not char

Tags: javascript, jquery, substr

I would like to limit the substr by words and not chars.  I am thinking regular expression and spaces but don't know how to pull it off.

Scenario: Limit a paragraph of words to 200 words using javascript/jQuery.

```
var $postBody = $postBody.substr(' ',200);
```

This is great but splits words in half :)  Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: It's nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 12):

```
function trim_words(theString, numWords) {
    expString = theString.split(/\s+/,numWords);
    theNewString=expString.join(" ");
    return theNewString;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if you're satisfied with a not-quite accurate solution, you could simply keep a running count on the number of space characters within the text and assume that it is equal to the number of words.

Otherwise, I would use split() on the string with " " as the delimiter and then count the size of the array that split returns.

Comment: Thanks guys :)  I now have a great way to get the count but with my limited abilities how do I take this and spit out a chunck of text limited to say 200 words?

I am able to get the overall count of spaces but not sure what to do with it :)  tnx.

 var $postLength = $postBody.split(/\s/).length

Comment: Are you saying that given a chunk of text that is perhaps 300 words long you would like to get the chunk containing the first 200 words? split(" ") will return the array of words, you would just have to loop through it and concatenate the first 200 elements of the array together. Or if you used my less accurate but much faster initial suggesting, you could just loop through the string counting the number of space characters and when you reach #200 take the substring from the start to the location of the 200th space.

Comment: Thanks for helping :)  here is the method I came up with:

var $i = 0;
var $maxWords = 50;

var $postBody = $("#myDiv").text().split(' ');

while($i < $maxWords){

  $("#results").append($postBody[$i] + " ");
  $i++;
 
}

Comment: looks like it will work. Make sure you give it a few good test cases to make sure it works as expected with multiple spaces in a row...and I'd look out for the possibility of going out of bounds on the array. If the postBody is less than $maxWords in length, it seems that "append($postBody[$i] + " ") would go out of bounds on the array once it reached the length of the post body.

Answer (score 1):

very quick and dirty

```
$("#textArea").val().split(/\s/).length
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you need to consider punctuation and other non-word, non-whitespace characters as well.  You want 200 words, not counting whitespace and non-letter characters.

```
var word_count = 0;
var in_word = false;

for (var x=0; x < text.length; x++) {
   if ( ... text[x] is a letter) {
      if (!in_word) word_count++;
      in_word = true;
   } else {
      in_word = false;
   }

   if (!in_word && word_count >= 200) ... cut the string at "x" position
}
```

You should also decide whether you treat digits as a word, and whether you treat single letters as a word.