# how to limit words in a div with jquery. I want to show only 3 words in a div and hide others

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to limit words in a div with jquery. I want to show only 3 words in a div and hide others

For example:

```
<div id="limit">
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
</div>
```

In result output I need only first three words using jquery: 
blah blah blah

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662308/javascript-substr-limit-by-word-not-char

Comment: You may want to look at [Lettering.js](http://letteringjs.com/).  You can use that to wrap the words, then use CSS rules from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy. All you need to do is to split the element contents and then slice them.

The working code will look like :

```
$(function() {
     // Handler for .ready() called.
    var divContent = $("#limit").text();
    var contentSpillage = divContent.split(" ");
    $("#limit").text( contentSpillage.slice(0,3) );
    });
```

See this fiddle to see the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/dx7DN/

Comment: No problem, happy to be of help .

Answer (score 1):

you can limit to your quantity with slice

```
function limitWords(element, quantity){

   var text = $(element).text();

   var words = text.split(" ");

   quantity = Math.min( quantity, words.length );

   $(element).text( words.slice(0,quantity) + "..." );

}
```